# Is there a way to toggle expanded table formatting mode in PrestoDB cli?

Tags: amazon-s3, command-line-interface, psql, presto

I am querying S3 buckets from [PrestoDB cli](https://prestodb.io/docs/current/installation/cli.html). I have a small display and I would love to have an equivalent command for `\x auto` in `psql`, which allows you to toggle expanded table formatting mode:

Before:

```
 id | time  |       humanize_time             | value 
----+-------+---------------------------------+-------
  1 | 09:30 |  Early Morning - (9.30 am)      |   570
  2 | 11:30 |  Late Morning - (11.30 am)      |   690
  3 | 13:30 |  Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)     |   810
  4 | 15:30 |  Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)     |   930
(4 rows)
```

After:

```
-[ RECORD 1 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 1
time          | 09:30
humanize_time | Early Morning - (9.30 am)
value         | 570
-[ RECORD 2 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 2
time          | 11:30
humanize_time | Late Morning - (11.30 am)
value         | 690
-[ RECORD 3 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 3
time          | 13:30
humanize_time | Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)
value         | 810
-[ RECORD 4 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 4
time          | 15:30
humanize_time | Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)
value         | 930
```

Is there a way to do this in PrestoDB cli? It does not look be documented at least.

Comment: You can enable record formatting by ending your query with '\G' instead of ';'.  For example, "SELECT 42 as foo \G"

Comment: @DainSundstrom Wow, that is exactly what I wanted, thank you!