# Enable expanded table formatting in HIVE CLI?

Tags: hive, hiveql, beeline

Similar to this question: [Is there a way to toggle expanded table formatting mode in PrestoDB cli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45031489/is-there-a-way-to-toggle-expanded-table-formatting-mode-in-prestodb-cli).

Is there a way to enable expanded table formatting mode in HIVE? I want to inspect a few records in a wide table before starting a big query job.

Copying the example from the other question:

Before expanded table formatting:

```sql
select * from sometable;

 id | time  |       humanize_time             | value 
----+-------+---------------------------------+-------
  1 | 09:30 |  Early Morning - (9.30 am)      |   570
  2 | 11:30 |  Late Morning - (11.30 am)      |   690
  3 | 13:30 |  Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)     |   810
  4 | 15:30 |  Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)     |   930
(4 rows)
```

After:

```sql
select * from sometable;

-[ RECORD 1 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 1
time          | 09:30
humanize_time | Early Morning - (9.30 am)
value         | 570
-[ RECORD 2 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 2
time          | 11:30
humanize_time | Late Morning - (11.30 am)
value         | 690
-[ RECORD 3 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 3
time          | 13:30
humanize_time | Early Afternoon - (1.30pm)
value         | 810
-[ RECORD 4 ]-+---------------------------
id            | 4
time          | 15:30
humanize_time | Late Afternoon - (3.30 pm)
value         | 930
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a combination of `CROSS JOIN` , `CASE` and `UNION ALL`.

```
select
  c.col,
  case c.col
    when 'id' then id
    when 'time' then time
    when 'humanize_time' then humanize_time
    when 'value' then value
  end as data
from sometable t
cross join
(
  select 'id' as col
  union all select 'time' as col
  union all select 'humanize_time' as col
  union all select 'value' as col
) c ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: thank you, but this doesn't quite do what I was looking for. I have a very wide table so adapting your query for my needs would be quite cumbersome. In postgresql, you can type `\x` to turn on extended display. I was hoping for something similarly as easy, but it doesn't seem that such a feature exists in HIVE at the moment.